# Javascript. How to stop repeated outputs of an array and add boolean values?

Tags: javascript, json

i'm doing a school exercise and am so close to getting it finished but just cant figure out this part. Not sure what to look up either seeing it is quite specific. What i'm trying to do is show the age for the four individuals and one is under 18 so it will show something different and does so successfully.
I will show a picture for better understanding.

[image]

What i want is to stop them repeating and have the different ages assigned to the four different people.

[image]

With this one im wanting to display if they are over 18, show true, if not then display false. But i want both of them to display at the same time.

Here is the code

```js
var iYear = [1995, 1986, 1991, 2002, 1999];
var iAges = [];
var iAdultAges = [];
var lenYear = iYear.length;
var iCurrent = 2017;
    for (var i = 0; i < lenYear; i++){
        var a = iCurrent - iYear[i];
        var iAge = iAges.push(a);
        console.log(iAges[0]);
    }
    for(x = 0; x < iAges.length; x++){               // x = 0 is a starting point
        if (iAges[x] < 18){                          // x < iAges.length is a ending point, this calculates it as 5
            iAdultAges.push(iAges[x]);               // x++ says how much we want the value to go up by.
            var YoungIndividual = iAges.indexOf(15);
            console.log("Person " + YoungIndividual + " is " + iAges[x] + " so they are NOT of age.");
        }else if (iAges[x] >= 18){
            iAdultAges.push(iAges[x]);
            console.log("Mary-Ann is " + iAges[x] + " years old and is of age.");
            console.log("Dale is " + iAges[x] + " years old and is of age.");
            console.log("Ali is " + iAges[x] + " years old and is of age.");
            console.log("Karl is " + iAges[x] + " years old and is of age.");
        }
    }
    function printAdultAge(iYear){
        var Ages = [];
        var adultAges = [];
        var booLean = ["True", "False"];
            for (var z = 0; z < lenYear; z++){
        var b = iCurrent - iYear[z];
        var age = Ages.push(b);
                console.log(iAges[0]);
   };
        for(e = 0; e < Ages.length; e++){               // e = 0 is a starting point
            if (Ages[e] < 18){                          // e < iAges.length is a ending point, this calculates it as 5
                iAdultAges.push(Ages[e]);               // e++ says how much we want the value to go up by.
                var YoungIndividual = Ages.indexOf(15);
                console.log("Person number " + YoungIndividual + " is " + Ages[e] + ". They are too young.");
                return booLean[1];
            }else if (Ages[e] >= 18){
                iAdultAges.push(Ages[e]);
                console.log("Mary-Ann is " + Ages[e] + ".");
                console.log("Dale is " + Ages[e] + ".");
                console.log("Ali is " + Ages[e] + ".");
                console.log("Karl is " + Ages[e] + ".");
                return booLean[0];
            }
        }
    };
console.log(printAdultAge(iYear));
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, it looks like you're overcomplicating this. The data given is an array of years? Are you also given the names, or are you making those up?

With the data given in your code, you can try something a lot simpler like this:

```
var years = [1995, 1986, 1991, 2002, 1999];
var yearsLength = years.length;
var ageThreshold = 18;
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

for (var i = 0; i < yearsLength; i++) {
   var personsAge = currentYear - years[i];
   var isOfAge = personsAge >= ageThreshold;
   console.log('Person ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + personsAge + ' years old');
   console.log(isOfAge);
}
```

[image]

If you are given the names in an array, you can access them with the same index (i), but it seems like there are 4 names and 5 year values so it would error when trying to read the 5th.

Comment: Thanks for that. Reason it looks very big is cause the brief states there needs to be a function which does the same steps. Thank you though